# Groovy nested map join

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
def bins = ['abc','def','ghf']
bins.each{bin ->
    def binsToAdd = [
        "$bin": "get${bin}ToAdd(getSwModule(), path)
    ]
    binPath = binsToAdd.findAll{it.key=="$bin"}.collect{
        item ->
            def comp = item.key
            def tars = item.value
            tars.collect {
                tar ->
                    def zipName = tar.tarName
                    def files = tar.fileNames
                    files.collect {
                        "$binFilesPath/$comp/$tarName!/$it"
                    }.join(',')
            }.join(',')
    }.join(',')
}
def getAbcToAdd (program, tStamp) {
    def binToAdd    = [:]
    binToAdd.int = [
        [
            archiveName: "${program}_${tStamp}.tar",
            fileNames: ['int.bin']
        ]
    ]
    binToAdd.ext = [
        [
            archiveName: "${program}_${tStamp}.tar",
            fileNames: ['ext.bin']
        ]
    ]

    return binToAdd."$program"
}
def getDefToAdd (program, tStamp) {
    def binToAdd    = [:]
    binToAdd.int = [
        [
            archiveName: "${program}_${tStamp}.tar",
            fileNames: ['int.bin']
        ]
    ]
    binToAdd.ext = [
        [
            archiveName: "${program}_${tStamp}.tar",
            fileNames: ['ext.bin']
        ]
    ]

    return binToAdd."$program"
}
```

I'm expecting binPath to have all bins path joined together as follows
`binPath = path/to/bin/tStamp/abc/int.bin,path/to/bin/tStamp/abc/ext.bin,path/to/bin/tStamp/def/int.bin,path/to/bin/tStamp/def/ext.bin`

but currently `path/to/bin/tStamp/def/int.bin,path/to/bin/tStamp/def/ext.bin`, pointing to the last bin path because of `bins.each{`
How can I change above such that I get what I'm looking for?

If I do as below then it works but I don't want to have this way because bins can be 1 or more; here just for an example I've hardcoded 3 items but I want "$bin" to be picked dynamically and process it accordingly.

```
def binFilesPath = 'some path'
def binsToAdd = [
    abc: getAbcToAdd(getSwModule(), path),
    def: getDefToAdd(getSwModule(), path),
    ghf: getGhfToAdd(getSwModule(), path)
]
def binPath = binsToAdd.findAll{it.key=="$bin"}.collect{
    item ->
        def comp = item.key
        def tars = item.value
        tars.collect {
            tar ->
                def zipName = tar.tarName
                def files = tar.fileNames
                files.collect {
                    "$binFilesPath/$comp/$tarName!/$it"
                }.join(',')
        }.join(',')
}.join(',')
```